# Is it possible to have HTML code reference something independent of filing system?

Tags: html

I'm not sure if i asked that question correctly but it was the best definition i could think of to explain what i'm trying to do. To elaborate:

I've written something and compiled it into an HTML document. The document references audio files that you can click on and have them play. It all works well, but only in the account i created the document on, and any other account or computer it can't reference the file.

The code below is, i think, the code it uses to reference one of the audio files on my hard drive which i found by opening the HTML document in a text editor.

```
<p class="p3"><a href="file:///Users/Ian/Desktop/Audio%20Discussion%20.html/Audio%20Files/z/Edits/Flute%201.mp3">Flute 1</a></p>
```

Is there any way to change that code so it always references the folder that the HTML document is contained in independent of whatever computer it's opened on?

If it helps, the containing folder will always have the same hierarchy (which you can see in the code above), the only thing that will change is the user (and the operating system, but if needed i could have several HTML documents, 1 for Windows, 1 for OSX and 1 for Linux).

This HTML document won't be on the web and will be offline. I'm trying to have the document self-contained and i haven't found anything that will allow me to do it but if this is possible i think it's a good idea. It sounds so simple but hey, what do i know.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do?

Comment: Just change the link so it's relative to the document, for example, `index.html`, and then a song linking to `music/song1.mp3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the `file://` protocol for linking files.
They can be just relative file paths.

For example:
If your html file is `Desktop/index.html`, and your audio files are in `Desktop/audio_files/`, then you can just link to the audio files using:
`<a href ="audio_files/filename.mp3">Flute 1</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can link via relative path. It propably looks familiar, using `./` at the start. If you skip that as well as the absolute link and use `href="folder/file.mp3"` it will also default to a relative path:

```
<p class="p3"><a href="./Audio%20Files/z/Edits/Flute%201.mp3">Flute 1</a></p>
```

Speaking of paths, try to prevent spaces and special characters.